# Extracting an optional field or default value in AWS ProcessingConfigurationProperty field

Tags: jq, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am working with AWS kinesis stream to create prefix for delivery output (S3), I chose JQ as parser and one of the prefix key is optional and I tried alternative option provided by jq but it is giving me an error. I have attached random AWS cloudtrail and the code snippet.

`

```
{
  "eventVersion": "1.08",
  "OptionalKey": "Optional" ---> I want to get the optional field and if it does not exist return "undefined"
  "userIdentity": {
    "type": "AssumedRole",
    "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:dkboss",
    "arn": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/dkboss",
    "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "sessionContext": {
      "sessionIssuer": {
        "type": "Role",
        "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "userName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "webIdFederationData": {},
      "attributes": {
        "creationDate": "2022-11-27T15:24:28Z",
        "mfaAuthenticated": "false"            }
    }
  },
  "eventTime": "2022-11-27T15:24:29Z",
  "eventSource": "signin.amazonaws.com", 
  "eventName": "ConsoleLogin",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "sourceIPAddress": "1.1.1.1",
  "userAgent": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "requestParameters": null,
  "responseElements": {
    "ConsoleLogin": "Success"
  },
  "additionalEventData": {
    "MobileVersion": "No",
    "MFAUsed": "No"
  },
  "eventID": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "readOnly": false,
  "eventType": "AwsConsoleSignIn",      
  "managementEvent": true,
  "recipientAccountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "eventCategory": "Management",
  "tlsDetails": {
    "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
    "cipherSuite": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "clientProvidedHostHeader": "signin.aws.amazon.com"
  }
}
```

`
I want to get build S3 prefix, but I couldn't figure out how optional values are supported.

`

```
 CfnDeliveryStream.ProcessorParameterProperty(
                            parameter_name="MetadataExtractionQuery",
                            parameter_value="{"
                            "tlsDetais : .tlsDetails.tlsVersion,"
                            'OptionalKey : .OptionalKey // "undefined",'
"}"
```

`
Inside ProcessorParameterProperty, But it failed with the following error:

```
JQ Subprocess failed due to: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected //, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>,
```

Comment: Please share the expected output and your current jq filter

Answer (score 0):

You have to group your expression with parentheses:

```
{
    tlsDetais : .tlsDetails.tlsVersion,
    OptionalKey : (.OptionalKey // "undefined")
}
```